# How to get values of multiple checkboxes in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Hi I have to create a groupbox with 6 checkboxes in it.  When multiple checkboxes are clicked the checkbox with the higher int. value will be displayed in a label. How do I do this?  How do I test the value of 6 checkboxes against the others and display the highest one that is checked?  So if say checkbox1 is checked it will display a 1 in a label.  So if multiple checkboxes are checked how can I just display the highest one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim Chk As CheckBox
Dim i As Integer = 0

For Each Chk In GrpBox.Controls

    If TypeOf (Chk ) Is CheckBox Then
        If Chk .checked Then
            If Chk .Tag > i Then i = Chk .Tag
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Ok where do I put that code then, in one of the checkbox subs?  Or in the main class?

Comment: You can put it in the form_load event thought I suggest that a better practice is to put it in your button's click event.  I presume you have button or something similar that the user clicks to generate an event; at which point you will need to evaluate your checkboxes.  Let me know if you have a different scenario.